Trino Iceberg remove_orphan_files deletes data, but does not delete metadata
I used Trino Iceberg and wanted to set up automatic deletion of old snips from data and metadata. expire_snapshots for some reason does not work (maybe I'm doing some kind of stupidity here, you can also prompt here).
And an important clarification is that I wrap all this in an asset for dagster (but this does not change the essence).
@asset(
name='optimized_iceberg',
description="Data extraction and optimization"
)
def optimized_iceberg(
    context: AssetExecutionContext,
) -\> None:
    conn = URL.create(
           "trino",
           host='host',
           port=443,
           database='db',
           username='user',
           password='password',
           query={
               "schema": 'schema',
               "http_scheme": "https",
               },
           )

    conn = create_engine(conn)
    a = conn.connect()
    
    # This query doesn`t work! Why?
    a.execute(text("ALTER TABLE schema.test_table EXECUTE expire_snapshots(retention_threshold => '7d')"))
    
    # This query doesn`t remove metadata. only data
    a.execute(text("ALTER TABLE schema.test_table EXECUTE            remove_orphan_files(retention_threshold => '7d')"))

remove_orphan_files works, but removes only from data but not metadata. I looked at the solution on the Internet+chatgpt+documentation but did not find an answer (gpt offered remove_orphan_meta_files and meta=true and path=meta and the like, but obviously there is no such thing in Trino Iceberg)
